# Why is the basis for this subbasis pair of points that are symmetric on the X axis

Tags: general-topology

> Let $S_1$ be the collection of all circles in the plane which have their centres on the $x$-axis. If $S_1$ is a subbasis for a topology $T_1$ on $\mathbb R^2$, describe the open sets in $(\mathbb R^2,T_1)$

The intersection of two circles on $x$-axis is either the empty set or one of those oval shapes when two circles intersect. So you do you conclude from that that the basis of this is the set of all point symmetric with the $x$-axis? (that is what the answer is saying)

Comment: Does "circle" refer to a disk or its boundary here?

Comment: What exactly is the answer saying?

Comment: circle refers to disks

Comment: @William It seems like it doesn't: The set $\{(0,1), (0,-1)\}$ is the intersection of two circle lines but isn't a union of finite intersections of disks.

Comment: @William: Since $S_1$ covers the plane, it is a subbase for a topology on the plane. With a bit of work you can show that all sets of the form $(a,b)\times(-c,c)$ are open in that topology, where $a,b,c\in\Bbb R^+$. I suspect that the family of such sets is a base for the topology.

Comment: Are the disks closed or open?